# Which costs more, computed goto/jump vs fastcall through function pointer?

Tags: c++, performance, function-pointers, goto, lookup-tables

I am in a dilemma, what would be the more performing option for the loop of a VM:

option 1 - force inline for the instruction functions, use computed goto for switch to go the call (effectively inlined code) of the instruction on that label... or...

option 2 - use a lookup array of function pointers, each pointing to a `fastcall` function, and the instruction determines the index.

Basically, what is better, a lookup table with jump addresses and in-line code or a lookup table with `fastcall` function addresses. Yes, I know, both are effectively just memory addresses and jumps back and forth, but I think `fastcall` may still cause some data to be pushed on the stack if out of register space, even if forced to use registers for the parameters.

Compiler is GCC.

Comment: I would suggest trying both, and profiling.  It would also be worth looking at the resulting assembler in each case, to clarify exactly what the compiler is doing.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - trying both with simple code will not likely give realistic results. In a VM the execution loop is kind of low level, so it is not like a few lines of work to try both cases, that is why I ask in advance so I can pick and work on the better solution.

Comment: I think option 1 would be faster, but I have not data to back this up.  Try to keep the switch values tightly packed.

Comment: "Computed goto"? I don't see a FORTRAN tag...

Comment: @PeteBecker - there is computed goto extension in GCC for C and C++. Don't know about other compiler vendors. Basically, there is a "get the address of label" operator to jump to.

Comment: Well, if it's too tricky to benchmark, what hope do we have predicting performance? Perhaps you should first accumulate some nontrivial programs for your VM before micro optimizing like this. It should be easy to overhaul the dispatch loop at any later stage. But my hopes aren't too high for either, for reasons Mike Pall (LuaJIT author) explained: http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.lua.general/75426

Comment: Found some data on this here http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/07/12/computed-goto-for-efficient-dispatch-tables

Answer (score 1):

I assume, that with "virtual machine", you refer to a simulated processor executing some sort of bytecode, similiar to the "Java virtual machine", and not a whole simulated computer that allows installation of another OS (like in VirtualBox/VMware).

My suggestion is to let the compiler do the decision, about what has the best performance, and create a big traditional "switch" on the current item of the byte code stream. This will likely result in a jump table created by the compiler, so it it as fast (or slow) as your computed goto variant, but more portable.

Your variant 2 - lookup array of function pointers - is likely slower than inlined functions, as there is likely extra overhead with non-inlined functions, such as the handling of return values. After all, some of your VM-op functions (like "goto" or "set-register-to-immediate") have to modify the instruction pointer, others don't need to.

Generally, calls to function pointers (or jumps via a jump table) are slow on current CPUs, as they are hardly predicted right by branch prediction. So, if you think about optimizing your VM, try to find a set of instructions, that requires as few code points as necessary.